# How to extract environment variable from process.environment in nodejs

Tags: node.js, dotenv

I have successfully integrated stripe payments in my dummy nodejs project. But still I'm left with an issue which doesn't let me move forward as I have to push code to my github repository. So, I installed dotenv package through npm and created a .env file for storing my stripe secret key. If I extract stripe secret key using process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY payment fails but If I pass STRIPE_SECRET_KEY directly payment succeeds.

I have even consoled process.env and it does show my stripe secret key.

This is my server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const cors = require('cors');

const payments = require('./routes/api/payment');

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors())

app.use('/api/payments', payments);

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('hello'));

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`server running on port: ${port}`));
```

This is my payment.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const stripe = require('stripe') (process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY); // this 
                                                       gives network error
const stripe = require('stripe') ("sk_test_O5le6FijZU4KcoxE4"); // this 
                                                           works gracefully
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json({
   message: 'Payment gateway works',
   time: Date.now
  });
})

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const credentials = {
  source: req.body.token.id,
  amount: req.body.amount,
  currency: "usd",
  description: req.body.description
}

stripe.charges.create(credentials, (err, response) => {
  if (err) {
  return res.status(400).json({ message: err })
   }
  return res.status(200).json({ message: response })
  })

  })

module.exports = router;
```

This is my .env file:

```
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = sk_test_O5le6FijZU4KcoxE4
```

directly passing stripe secret key to the stripe works but it fails if I provide stripe secret key using process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY.
I want process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY to work so that I can push code to my github repository safely and securely.

Answer (score 3):

I see the problem here
You need to initialize dontenv after main imports!

```js
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

dotenv.config(); // here after main imports

// After dotenv.config() payment.js will have dontenv values!!
const payments = require('./routes/api/payment');
```

Comment: Ok, then lets give it a try

Comment: Can you console.log(process.env. STRIPE_SECRET_KEY) and console.log(process.env) ?

Comment: Can you look again the edited answer, I see the problem here @AvadheshKumar

Comment: I've consoled process.env my stripe key is present there. Let me give a try to this edited answer. Hope it works

Comment: already accepted dude but I guess there is no problem with space as you mentioned earlier

Comment: I was the one who have asked this question but from a differenrt account. Therefor you got 2 upvotes

Answer (score 0):

You have to change in server.js file for dotenv npm. 
Like `**require('dotenv').config();**`
then after may be you have export process env.

```
module.exports = {
  STRIPE_SECRET_KEY: process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY,
};
```

Comment: I don't think so because I;ve consoled process.env and the key is present there

Comment: have you try export variable in server.js file? because without export you can not access process.env variable

Comment: Thanks a lot bro for helping but @onuriltan has already gave the working solution

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using NestJS, initialize the stripe client in the constructor:

```
private stripe;

constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {
    this.stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_API_SECRET);
}
```