# process.env working when i console.log but will not work when i plug in to key

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments, dotenv

I have an app that uses node and stripe to make payments, however, when I hid the key in the .env file and plugged it in, it will not work. I can log out the key by calling process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY.

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const env = require("dotenv").config({ path: "../../.env" });
// const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
console.log(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
router.post("/", function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.charge.amount);
  const token_id = req.body.charge.source;
  const purchase_price = req.body.charge.amount;
  const email = req.body.receipt_email;
  console.log(req.body.receipt_email);

  const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

  // `source` is obtained with Stripe.js; see https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-charges#web-create-token
  stripe.charges.create(
    {
      amount: 1000,
      currency: "usd",
      source: "tok_visa",
      description: "My First Test Charge (created for API docs)",
      receipt_email: email,
    },
    function (err, charge) {
      if (err && err.type === "StripeCardError") {
        res.json({ status: "failure", reason: "card was declined" });
      } else {
        console.log(charge);
        res.json({ status: "Success!" });
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Is the relative path for `../../.env` accurate from where the node process is being started? Have you verified that your `.env` file is accurate with the variable name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract environment variable from process.environment in nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57882573/how-to-extract-environment-variable-from-process-environment-in-nodejs)